# Select and add item back to mysql using ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is my first post on SO and i would really appreciate if i could get some answers on a problem i'm having.

Basically i'm doing a simple shopping page where you click and list products using ajax. This will list items with button ADD. What i want to do is to to be able to click this button which will result in adding element into temporary mysql table. Sor far it's all working fide finding elements but i'm stuck at this stage.

here is my form bit:

```
<div id="divsearch">
            <form>
                <input name="searchfield" type="text" value="Search the store" size="60"/><input value="Search" type="button" name="submit" onclick="showResults(document.getElementsByName('searchfield')[0].value)"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and this is js function:

```
function showResults(str)

  {
    var str;

    if (str==="")
    {
        document.getElementById("div-main").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("div-main").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","search_results_aNL.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and the PHP DB script:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

require_once 'db.php';
require_once 'error.php';


// Step 1
if (!($conn = mysql_connect($config['server'], $config['user'], $config['password'])))
{
    showError();
}

// Step 2
if (!(mysql_select_db($config['database'], $conn)))
{
    showError();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE make LIKE '%$q%' OR description LIKE '%$q%' OR type LIKE '%$q%'";

if (!($result = mysql_query($query, $conn)))
{
    showError();
}

$count = 0;
    echo "The q is " . $q . "<br />";
    echo $query;
    echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Product ID</td>
        <td>Make</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Hdd</td>
        <td>Ram</td>
        <td>Quantity in stock</td>
        <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Info </td>
                    <td> Full Info </td>

        ";
echo "</tr>";
// Step 4
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // Step 5

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $row[id]</td>
        <td>$row[make]</td>
        <td>$row[type]</td>
        <td>$row[hdd]</td>
        <td>$row[ram]</td>
        <td>$row[quantity]</td>
        <td>$row[price]</td>;
                    <td>$row[description]</td>
                    <td>$row[description_more]</td>
                    <td><input type='button' value='Add'/></td>"
                    ;
    echo "</tr>";


    $count ++;
}
    echo "</table>";
if ($count == 0)
{
    echo "<blink><font color=\"red\">No matches!</font></blink>";
}
// Step 6
mysql_close($conn);
```

?>

Could someone please give some hits what should i write to get this button working? the table that will post information back will be called basket. do i have to use similar JS function with POST command?
Thanks
L

Comment: not the answer you are looking for but... SANITIZE YOUR DATABASE INPUTS kkthx ;) also mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

First create a button calling a javascript function as such :

```
<input type="button" name"some_name" onclick="add_item('variables_to_pass')" />
```

after that create your function in script tags that will call an exertnal php file to process the request as such :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    function add_item(){
    //your code here
    //you can place your ajax request in this function as well
    }
    </script>
```

the last create your php file to process your request and do not forget to pass necessary variable values to the page.

```
<?php
//your php code here to handle the request.
//Do not use mysql_* functions for they are deprecated
?>
```

Comment: done that, i've modified the php file where there is button section: <td><input type='button' value='Add'/></td>" to <td><input name='itemQ' type='text' size='2'/><input type='submit' value='Add' onclick='addItems(document.getElementsByName('id').value,document.getElementsByName('price').value),document.getElementsByName('itemQ')[0].value)'></td>"; so it returns values from the table but when i click ADD chrome throws the following: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } ... any thoughts?

Comment: means there is a typo on your javascript. find it and test it again. if you can use jquery and ajax in it, it would've been easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need quotes around the data field name. Like this:

```
echo '<td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>'
echo '<td>' . $row["make"] . '</td>'
```

and so on...